# DataTimeControl validation Issues (no clearing error message)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime, sharepoint, web

I write simple WebPart with few asp.net controls.
I have problem with validation control and SharePoint date time control. 
The markup:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtc" runat="server" DateOnly="true" HoursMode24="true" OnDateChanged="dtc_DateChanged"/>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="valDtc" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="dtc$dtcDate"
            Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck"  ErrorMessage="choose or write correct date (YYYY-MM-DD)">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
```

If I write some wrong date I have error message, if I write correct date message disappear. But after I choose other (correct) date from calendar the error message does not disappear (but should).
How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

Trying to use SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator:

```
<SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator ID="ifval" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="dtc"
            Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" EnableClientScript="true"  ErrorMessage="choose or write correct date (YYYY-MM-DD)">
            </SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator>
```

gives me error:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Control 'dtc' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'ifval' cannot be validated.]
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.CheckControlValidationProperty(String name, String propertyName) +11200546
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() +50
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator.ControlPropertiesValid() +72
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.get_PropertiesValid() +44
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +38
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.InputFormCompareValidator.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +131
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
```

if I change ControlToValidate="dtc" to "dtc$dtcDate" it behaves the same as CompareValidator and error message does not disappear after choosing good date.

[image: Picture:]

Comment: Have you tried using SharePoint InputFormCompareValidator control instead of asp.net control?

Comment: Thank you Yavgeniy for comment. I do not try it. I will search information about it and I will reply how it works.

Comment: <SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator ID="ifval" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="dtc$dtcDate"
                Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" EnableClientScript="true"  ErrorMessage="error date (YYYY-MM-DD)">
                </SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator>   - unfortunately the result is the same

Comment: Why you set "ControlToValidate" to "dtc$dtcDate"? It should be just "dtc"

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I edit question trying use SharePoint:InputFormCompareValidator